# Unable to Identify Icon Set Family

Tags: html, icons, webfonts

I have a bootstrap/HTML template in which an Icon Family is present which i tried a lot to identify and search but i couldn't. Empty boxes are being shown instead of icons. I tried to search it as Iconly, but there is no CDN or library i have found to integrate into my template.

Here is my Head Tag code

```
<head>
    
    <title>Gift</title>

    <!-- Google font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

    <!-- bootstrap css -->
    <link id="rtl-link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendors/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- wow css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css">

    <!-- font-awesome css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendors/font-awesome.css">

    <!-- feather icon css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendors/feather-icon.css">

    <!-- Plugin CSS file with desired skin css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendors/ion.rangeSlider.min.css">

    <!-- slick css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendors/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendors/slick/slick-theme.css">

    <!-- animation css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/LinearIcons/icon-font.min.css">

    <!-- Template css -->
    <link id="color-link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
```

Here are those icons sets in HTML Code

`<i class="iconly-Swap icli"></i>`

`<i class="iconly-Swap icli"></i>`

Comment: instead of an answer or a guideline, a minus vote. Thats a Wow

Comment: If you can't find the related icon library, consider it replacing with others like fontawesome, tabular etc

Comment: I agree with Team Thunder: Better choose *one* icon library that matches your requirements – otherwise you're loading way too many data and might also risk conflicts. Apparently, your code uses an iconly (not even sure if there are multiple projects using this name) set. If you can't find a decent cheat cheat listing all available icons – don't use it! But please always try to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)